# Running jar file in cmd in Windows gives error

Tags: java

I have downloaded a jar file called beagle.14Jan16.841.jar from [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/browning/beagle/beagle.html) and am trying to run it in cmd using the line

```
java –Xmx8g –jar beagle.14Jan16.841.jar gt=beaglefilt.vcf out=beagleoutput
```

My cmd directory is the location of the beagle.14Jan16.841.jar file.

The error I get is `Error: Could not find or load main class ?Xmx8g`

My java is up to date and PATH leads to my java bin folder (`java -version` works).

Comment: Do you need the `–Xmx8g` argument?

Comment: Have you added your jar file to the class path?

Comment: The jar file is in my current cmd directory. Do I still need to add it to the class path? If so, how if the jar file is in `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Research`?

Comment: Yes, you do. set classpath=%classpath%;.\beagle.14Jan16.841.jar. Do the same thing if it's somewhere else. Just include the full path

Comment: I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is in <kbd>-</kbd> character,in your error say it as <kbd>?</kbd>

Try to copy this command and run it:

```
java –jar beagle.14Jan16.841.jar gt=beaglefilt.vcf out=beagleoutput
```

Comment: Then I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class ?jar`

Comment: You're right about the character difference. I initially wrote it somewhere else and was trying to copy and paste it. Thank you.